# Why does a sequence of unhappy numbers always loop back to itself?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given a positive integer $19$, it is said to be happy, because $1^2 + 9^2 = 82$, $8^2+2^2 = 68$, $6^2 + 8^2 = 100$, $1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1$. At each step we simply sum the square of all its digits, and if at some step the sum is equal to $1$, then we say this number is happy, otherwise unhappy. It is true that for an unhappy number $n$, it will always loop back to itself. Why is this true?

Comment: I don't think it's true that an unhappy number will always loop back to itself.  It will eventually go into a cycle, but the original number may not be part of the cycle.  For example $85\rightarrow 89\rightarrow 145\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow 58 \rightarrow 89$.  This never comes back to $85$.

Comment: http://by.tc/happy.png  -- values for first 300 if I understand right.

Comment: Better yet: http://by.tc/happy_graph.png -- this shows the two essential possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

This is untrue.  $2$ is unhappy and does not loop back to itself: $$2\to4\to16\to37\to58\to89\to145\to42\to20\to4$$

Comment: Whoops, had a bug. You're right.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: for any number greater than 99 the sum of the squared digits is less than the number. So either the sequence terminates at 1, or the sequence gets trapped in a loop. Then with a little more effort one can show that the only loop is  4 -16 - 37 - 58 - 89 - 145 - 42 - 20 - 4.